# Create calculated field in a table with DDL SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, field, ddl

I'm trying to add a calculated field on a Access table in a `SQL` sentence

```
CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE
```

I've managed to make it through a `TableDef` but failed to find any information on how to do it using `SQL`

Is that possible?

Comment: I would try (the SQL-Server syntax): `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN columnName AS (expression) ;` and see if it raises error.

Comment: Also read this page about limitations of calculated columns: [Calculated Fields in Access 2010](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)